# Share file in slack from one user to another user using api

Tags: python, slack-api

I want to share slack file from one user to another user within the same workspace using api.

What I tried in code is, downloaded the file want to share and uploaded the file to the user using files.upload method.
But both the files are assigned with the different file ids.

Is there any way to share the file from one user to another without changing its file id using api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Slack you can usually share files with others. (as described [here](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201330736-Uploading-and-sharing-files))

However, this is currently not possible with the Slack API, since it does not have a method for sharing a file, other then through [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload).

Alternatively you can use the [`files.share`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/files.share.md) method from the **undocumented** Slack API. This comes with a couple caveats though, one being that the method requires a [legacy token](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) and will therefore not work well with distributed Slack apps. But if you are just building something for your own Slack workspace it will work fine.

To share a file with another user provide the user ID as `channel` property for `files.share`.

Note: If you need this functionality I would suggest to let the Slack team know about it. The more feedback they get the more likely this method will become part of the official API.